# R crashes when trying to save list object ~1gb in size

Tags: r, save

I have a list object that includes many .wav files. Collectively, the .wav files are ~1gb in size. I've been trying to save the list object in a .Rdata file, like this:

```
save(my_list_of_wavs, file = 'wavs.Rdata')
```

After running this function, R does not respond and I need to force R to quit. Is there any other function or workaround I can use to save the .Rdata file?

Comment: I'm wondering if you did not wait long enough.

Comment: How long does it take to save smaller wavs? Extrapolate this to the size of your data, and if its not done after 30 times that extrapolation then I'd say it was stuck. Also, what operating system, what version of everything, and what file system? Maybe your file system doesn't like large files.

Comment: for what it's worth, I would say that the term "hangs" may be a more precise description of your problem than "crashes".  To me "crashes" means the program terminates ...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @IShouldBuyABoat, you might need to wait more.
To make saving faster you can turn off compression:

```
save(my_list_of_wavs, file = 'wavs.Rdata', compress=FALSE)
```